# Minimizing a function problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm solving an elastoplastic problem of the Ducker Prager model using the closest point projection method, which consists of minimizing a distance between a trial stress and the yield surface in the principal stress space.
I need to to find the values of the variables `xi` and `beta` that minimize the following square distance function:

```
rho = Sqrt[2] (B c - A xi);
sstarsurface = {xi/Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[2/3] rho Cos[beta], 
   xi/Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[2/3] rho Cos[beta - 2 Pi/3], 
   xi/Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[2/3] rho Cos[beta + 2 Pi/3]};
diff = {sig1trial, sig2trial, sig3trial} - sstarsurface;
eq = diff.diff (*need to minimize this function!*)
```

Where `A`, `B` and `c` are material constants.
I tried this:

```
Minimize[eq, {xi, beta}]
```

But obtained no success. Then I tried this and it works, but the result is too cumbersome:

```
deq = {D[eq, xi], D[eq, beta]}
Solve[deq == 0, {xi, beta}] // Simplify
```

Does anyone has an idea on how to simplify this result?

Comment: First of all just because the derivative is zero doesn't mean that you have a minimum.

Comment: I think the problem is that beta is the angle of the Cos function and this creates the problem. Instead use the t1=Cos[beta], Sqrt[1-t1^2]=Sin[beta] and then use the Minimize. It still won't be easy because the result will be have many conditions such as the parameters being real or not etc... But at least it is doing something then.

Comment: @Buddha thank tou for tour comments. The constants are real values and the stresses sig1trial>sig2trial>sig3trial

Comment: The Square distance function has two minimuns since It is a distance relative to a volume in the space. Using the derivative equal to zero gives these two possible solutions

Comment: Ok, you are right.

Comment: I plopped values for all of the constants in there (no idea if realistic) and tried it, and it solved. Is it that you are trying to find an expression for all parameters values?

Comment: @MikeY i'm trying to find in a closed for the expressions for xi and beta which minimizes eq.

Comment: *closed form. The expressions are in function of the constants.

Comment: I noticed if you set the the sigTrials equal to each other (but still symbolic) you get a closed form.

Comment: Thats interesting, but it's also odd because when the stresses are equal tou should be inside the yield Surface...

Comment: The yield Surface in question os the DruckerPrager. In the stress space It has a cone shape

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify your result using Weierstrass substitution to force `-Pi<beta<Pi`

```
glnu = (1 + u^2) deq /. beta -> 2 ArcTan[u] // TrigExpand // FullSimplify
(Solve[glnu == 0 , {u, xi }] // FullSimplify) /. u -> Tan[beta/2]
```

This gives a simpler result without ConditionalExpression!

**remark**
the substitution gives a functional `J = (1 + u^2) eq /. beta -> 2 ArcTan[u] // TrigExpand // Simplify` which is quadratic in u and xi. Perhaps Minimize can solve this problem?

Comment: Newmann Thank you for your answer! But I didn' t understand. What is `glnu` and `gln`? Should I use your code in my solution?

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer: Just substitute `gln` by `deq`!

Comment: Very good, thank you!

Comment: @Diogo You're welcome. The definition of J in my answer is  the cone shape I think.