# Is it possible to find a closed solution for this problem?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I need to find the global minimum of the following function:

```
eq=(sig1tr/Sqrt[3] + sig2tr/Sqrt[3] + sig3tr/Sqrt[3] - xi)^2/(
 3 K) + ((Sqrt[2/3] sig1tr - sig2tr/Sqrt[6] - sig3tr/Sqrt[6] - 
    Sqrt[2] (A - C E^(Sqrt[3] B xi)) Cos[beta])^2 + (sig2tr/Sqrt[2] - 
    sig3tr/Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[2] (A - C E^(Sqrt[3] B xi)) Sin[beta])^2)/(
 2 G)
```

Where `G>0, K>0, A>0,C>0,B>0, sigtr1,sigtr2 and sigtr3` are real constants.  Aditionaly `sigtr1>sigtr2>sigtr3`.  I need to find the variables values of`xi and beta` that minimizes `eq`.

In this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188285/minimizing-a-function-problem) a previous discussion about a simular issue was made.

I tried this:

```
Minimize[eq, {xi, beta}]
```

and this:

```
dfunc = {D[eq, xi], D[eq, beta]};
Solve[dfunc == 0, {xi, beta}]
```

but I got no luck.

Any ideas? Is it possible to solve this analyticaly?

If we substitute numerical values to the constants and plot the funtion we get:

```
subst = {A -> 0.25, B -> 0.67, C -> 0.18, G -> 40, K -> 66.6667, 
   sig1tr -> -0, sig2tr -> -0.1, sig3tr -> -0.3};
    pl = eq //. subst
    Plot3D[pl, {xi, -0.5, 0.1}, {beta, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: For numeric values of parameters, `Minimize[eq /. {A -> 0.25, B -> 0.67, C -> 0.18, G -> 40, 
   K -> 66.6667, sig1tr -> -0, sig2tr -> -0.1, sig3tr -> -0.3}, {xi, 
  beta}]` or `Minimize[{eq, -Pi < beta <= Pi} /. {A -> 0.25, B -> 0.67, C -> 0.18, 
   G -> 40, K -> 66.6667, sig1tr -> -0, sig2tr -> -0.1, 
   sig3tr -> -0.3}, {xi, beta}]`

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment rather than a symbolic solution.  As noted in the question,

```
Minimize[eq, {xi, beta}]
```

returns unevaluated.  Consider, instead, the simpler problem of minimizing `eq` over `beta` only.  Then the first term in `eq` is a constant and can be ignored.  Unfortunately,

```
Minimize[eq // Last, beta]
```

also returns unevaluated.  Next, note that `eq // Last` is equivalent to

```
eq1 = c ((c1 + Cos[beta])^2 + (c2 + Sin[beta])^2);
```

if the constants `c`, `c1`, and `c2` are appropriately defined.  But, `Minimize[eq1, beta]` again returns unevaluated.  `eq1` can, however, be minimized by using the Weierstrass substitution, suggested in the link provided in the question.

```
eq2 = eq1 /. beta -> 2 ArcTan[u] // TrigExpand // FullSimplify
(* c ((-1 + c1)^2 + c2^2 + (4 (c1 + c2 u))/(1 + u^2)) *)
Simplify[Minimize[eq2, u], c != 0 && c1 != 0 && c2 != 0]
(* {-2 Sqrt[c^2 (c1^2 + c2^2)] + c (1 + c1^2 + c2^2), 
    {u -> (c c2)/(c c1 - Sqrt[c^2 (c1^2 + c2^2)])}} *)
```

It is natural to ask, therefore, whether the Weierstrass substitution would allow `eq // Last` to be minimized directly.  Surprisingly, it does not.  So, consider the expression,

```
eq5 = c ((c1 + (A - E^xi) Cos[beta])^2 + (c2 + (A - E^xi) Sin[beta])^2);
eq6 = eq5 /. beta -> 2 ArcTan[u] // TrigExpand // FullSimplify
(* c (c1^2 + c2^2 + E^(2 xi) + (A (A + 2 c1 + 4 c2 u + (A - 2 c1) u^2) - 
      2 E^xi (A + c1 + 2 c2 u + (A - c1) u^2))/(1 + u^2)) *)
Simplify[Minimize[eq6, u], c != 0 && c1 != 0 && c2 != 0]
```

It returns unevaluated, even though `eq5` is equivalent to `eq1` with constants appropriately defined.  Moreover, `Minimize[eq6, u]` returns unevaluated instantly.  All this suggests to me that `Minimize` will not even try to obtain a solution, if the expression to be minimized contains many parameters. In any case, the constants in the expression for `u` obtained for `eq2` can be transformed algebraically to the original set of constants in `eq`, which we then could attempt to minimize over `xi`.  It seems unlikely that doing so would be successful, though, because the resulting expression for `eq` would be complicated, transcendental, and contain very many parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Using numeric values

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

assume = -Pi < beta <= Pi;

Manipulate[
 eq = (sig1tr/Sqrt[3] + sig2tr/Sqrt[3] + sig3tr/Sqrt[3] - 
        xi)^2/(3 K) + ((Sqrt[2/3] sig1tr - sig2tr/Sqrt[6] - 
          sig3tr/Sqrt[6] - 
          Sqrt[2] (A - C E^(Sqrt[3] B xi)) Cos[beta])^2 + (sig2tr/
           Sqrt[2] - sig3tr/Sqrt[2] - 
          Sqrt[2] (A - C E^(Sqrt[3] B xi)) Sin[beta])^2)/(2 G) // 
   Simplify[#, assume] &;
 {val, param} = NMinimize[{eq, assume}, {xi, beta}];
 Column[{
   StringForm["minimum = `1`\nparameters: `2`", 
    ScientificForm[val, 6], param],
   Show[
    Plot3D[eq, {xi, -2, 2}, {beta, -Pi, Pi},
     PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.75],
     ClippingStyle -> None,
     AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"xi", "beta", "eq "})],
    Graphics3D[{Blue, AbsolutePointSize[8], 
      Point[{xi, beta, val} /. param]}],
    ImageSize -> 396]}],
 Grid[{
   {Control[{{A, 0.25}, 10^-3, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
    Control[{{B, 0.67}, 10^-3, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
   {Control[{{C, 0.18}, 10^-3, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
    Control[{{G, 40}, 10^-6, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
   {Control[{{K, 66.6667}, 10^-6, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
    SpanFromLeft},
   {Control[{{sig1tr, 0}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
    Control[{{sig2tr, -0.1}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
   {Control[{{sig3tr, -0.3}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
    SpanFromLeft}},
  Alignment -> Left],
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]